# Filtering out processes Windows File Audit (event 4663)

Tags: windows, security, audit

I would like to use Windows File Audit to monitor access to a set of files on my system (i.e. event 4663).  I noticed that most of the events generated is noise from a few processes.  I would like a way to effectively blacklist these processes, e.g. don't log an event if the file access was from the local AV process.  Can't seem to find any documentation on configuring this and I'm starting to fear that it is not a supported use case.

Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: `it is not a supported use case`. That would be what I am inclined to think.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom view in the Event Viewer:

Right click on **Custom Views** -> **Create Custom View**.

As you want to filter on a specific value in the event data, we have to create an advanced query, so click on the "**XML**" tab and use a query like this one:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">*[System[(EventID=4663)]]</Select>
    <Suppress Path="Security">*[EventData[Data[@Name='ProcessName'] and (Data='c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe') ]]</Suppress>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Note that we have a "Select" (to select everything with EventID 4663 in the Security log), and a "Suppress" to remove events matching the filter.

Now, your custom view will list events with ID 4663 if they don't match the Suppress filter.

You can learn more about custom views and advanced filtering here:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2011/09/26/advanced-xml-filtering-in-the-windows-event-viewer/

Comment: Thanks @Swisstone for the response. I don't want to filter when viewing the data, I rather want to filter what is collected.  Example:  Collect file-access events unless the process accessing the file is process A.

Comment: Are you using Windows Event Forwarding to centralize the logs ?

Comment: Something similar, yes.  The concern is that if the endpoint is offline and the sensor (Windows File Auditor) generates too many events of little interest, we may miss valuable events because the log may wrap.

Comment: With Windows Event Forwarding, you can use the same query to filter the events collected on the endpoints. However, you can't configure Windows File Audit to discard these events.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is the latter that we are looking for.